# MySQL: execute an "UPDATE" only if an specific row exists

Tags: mysql

I want to execute an UPDATE clause only in the case a specific row exists. Specifically, if a row in `gallery_image` exists with a specified `position`, I want to update all rows with a `position` higher than that value, flipping the sign of the `position` value.

So this is my try:

```
IF SELECT * FROM gallery_image WHERE position = 'X' 
UPDATE gallery_image SET position = position * -1
```

but I get an error.

**EDIT**: After the first comment after my question I have tried this:

```
update gallery_image if ( EXISTS ( select * from gallery_image position = 8 )) set position = position * -1
```

but it says

> An alias was found before. (near "(" at position 24)"

Comment: So... What's the error?

Comment: it says "if" is unknown, I have spanish language. In spanish it is: `Tipo de declaración desconocida. (near "if" at position 0)`

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists).

Comment: The way you've written your SQL, you want to update *all* rows in the table if and only if a certain row exists? Or do you only want to update rows *that match that criteria*?

Comment: @BradC the first one you mention.

Comment: Actually, I want to do, as you maybe can guess, is update (* -1) the column `position` of the rows with a `position` value greater than the value submitted by the user, only if the "position" submitted exist on the table.

Comment: May be you can check the syntax for `UPDATE` in the manual -- it's pretty basic.

Comment: @JavierGarcia we ask again. Do you want to update all rows of the table or only rows with `position = X`? or something else?

Comment: FYI - edited in my understanding of your explanation of what you want to do into your post. Please review and (if needed) either roll back to remove, or edit to correct. You may want to comment if it's fine as is.

Comment: Could you give us an example of what your data looks like? Specifically for the `gallery_image` table. I guess you want something like: `UPDATE gallery_image SET position = position * -1 WHERE position IS NOT NULL AND id = <current_id_of_image_being_processes>`.

Answer (score 1):

The `IF` *statement* can only be used inside Stored Routines.  This explains the syntax error.

Are you trying to change *all* rows in the table if a certain row exists?

It's a bit clumsy, but here is a purely SQL way:

```
SET @x := EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM gallery_image WHERE position = 8 );
UPDATE gallery_image
    SET position = - position
    WHERE @x;
```

(It is not normal to change all rows of a table.  What is the application doing?  Can it be achieved without such a massive query?)

If you only want to change the one row with `8`:

```
UPDATE gallery_image
    SET position = - position
    WHERE position = 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, in order to use flow control statements (IF, WHILE, etc.), as in your first statement, you have to be in a stored procedure.

You also cannot perform `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM gallery_image ...)` within the `UPDATE` statement itself (as you were presumably trying to do in your second statement).

If you don't want/need to create a stored procedure, you can capture the count of rows that meet your check, and only do the UPDATE if that count is greater than 0:

```
SET @user_position = 8;

SET @position_exists := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gallery_image WHERE position = @user_position);

UPDATE gallery_image
   SET position = (-1) * position
 WHERE @position_exists > 0
   AND position > @user_position
;
```

Here's a [db-fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sHHpNvqCMVFxnCV8Z6qMct/1), showing this works as you've said you want it to.

---

A few additional notes on your two statements:

Even in a stored procedure, I don't think your first statement would work as written. The `IF` was expecting a Boolean value, TRUE or FALSE - your first query gave it multiple rows with (I assume) multiple columns. If you wrapped the statement in an `EXISTS`, then it may work in a stored proc.

I'm not immediately acquainted with using an `IF` statement like you tried to in your second statement, inside an UPDATE statement (MySQL isn't my "first" language); if it is valid to structure things that way, then the problem may involve you leaving out the keyword `WHERE` in the `SELECT` statement. Without the `WHERE`, the `SELECT` would interpret `position` as an alias for `gallery_image`. Alternately, if you cannot use `IF` as you are, then `IF` might be being interpreted as an alias for `gallery_image` in the `UPDATE` statement.

However, of course, the second statement would only work if you were checking a different table for a value - as noted above, you can't perform an `EXISTS` check on the table you're updating inside the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: My apologies if you saw my first attempt at an answer; this version is confirmed as working via db-fiddle.com.